# SQL query to find distinct sub-strings

Tags: sql, regex, mysqli

I have a table with a column that has strings where the first two letters are country indentifiers (US,CN,RU,etc), and the next 3 characters are the identifiers that I want to capture. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: [**`substring`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring)

Comment: Just need to add a `distinct`, but this works. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 3, 3) ...
```

And here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08c34/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column, 1, 2) [country]
     , SUBSTRING(column, 3, 3) [identifier]
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(field, 3, 3) from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select substring(column,3,3) from table